# How to prevent springboot gateway to forward to last element in the chain

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using springboot gateway for load balancing requests between my microservice

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service  
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: baeldung
        uri: question.com/questions/444/ask
      - id: myOtherRouting
        uri:  answer.com/answers/333/answer
```

my problem is, if i send a wrong request like `"question.com/questions/dasldkjasdas"`
then the request is forwarded to `answer.com/answers/333/answer`
since this is the last chain in my config, how can i prevent this, and send notfound statuscode as response. I used

```
filters:
            - SetStatus=NOT_FOUND
```

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#setstatus-gatewayfilter-factory

but this is not the best approuch i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any `predicate` specified for your `route` definitions - which means both of them match any incoming request. From [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#glossary):

> Clients make requests to Spring Cloud Gateway. If the Gateway Handler Mapping determines that a request matches a Route, it is sent to the Gateway Web Handler.

and

> **Route**: Route the basic building block of the gateway. It is defined by an ID, a destination URI, a collection of predicates and a collection of filters. A route is matched if aggregate predicate is true.

Since you don't have any `predicate` specified - your route matches the incoming request and the last one is winning.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it works now, and i get for unknown uri this log: `OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found`
but how can i make it asa logError in order to see it in sentry?